# Finding the words that start with a given letter from a list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to find the words that start with a particular letter from a list of strings. The user will input the list of words and the starting letter. For example, something like:

> "table pencil chair desk pen" "p"

So the words that start with `p` should be displayed, in this case `pen` and `pencil`. My first step is to split the string into a list of strings using the `words` function. Then how do I find what letter each word starts with? The type of the function will look like:

```
--------------Find words Starting with a given letter------------------

findWords :: String -> Char -> [String]
```

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, you should tag it as such.

Comment: This is a school book example of the kind of task that is little work in haskell. Now, give it a try yourself and then if you still need our help, come back here. However, I wouldn't be surprised if you don't need our help anymore then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `filter`,

```
foo string = filter startsWithP (words string)
```

then you need to define

```
startsWithP :: String -> Bool
```

More useful will be the generic variant

```
startsWith :: String -> Char -> Bool
```

to be used like `` "foo" `startsWith` 'f' ``.

Comment: Thanks @dave, some day I will learn when double backticks are necessary and when not.

Comment: Backticks are just used for infix form, in this case to make the function call read more like proper English ("foo" startsWith 'f'). It's exactly the same as calling: `startsWith "foo" 'f'`

Comment: @shang I know that, I was referring to the markup where backticks are used to create inline code blocks. So to use backticks for infix function application inside inline code blocks, sometimes they have to be escaped by writing two backticks (I think in comments, let me try `"foo" \`startsWith\` 'f'`), and sometimes apparently not. Hm, no, double backticks also show as double backticks in comments, must have misremembered the escaping rules.

Comment: I am new to haskell. I don't get the above code. I need to output the list of words that are beginning with a letter specified by the user as i have mentioned above. I know how to use filter on integers but not on strings specially in this case where i have to filter by the starting letter. Please help.

Comment: @Sindu_ `filter` works the same, regardless of type, `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. In `findWords`, the type of list elements is `String`, so you get `filter :: (String -> Bool) -> [String] -> [String]`. You need to create the filtering condition from the `Char` argument, then `findWords c input = filter (condition c) (words input)` will do the desired.

Comment: thank you.okay I got it now.How will the condition look like if i need to check if the word starts with the letter specified by the user? Is there a keyword for that?

Comment: There are several ways, the usual way is to use pattern matching. You won't learn it if we spoon-feed you the complete solution, so play around a bit with it and read about defining functions in your book or tutorial. It's not hard when you've understood how pattern matching and guards work.

Answer (score 4):

Hint #1: in Haskell a `String` is defined as a list of `Chars`, so all the list functions are available.

Answer (score 1):

Since you really want to know the strings that start with a given string (according to your post) I'd use the `isPrefixOf` function:

```
filter ("p" `isPrefixOf`)  ["cats", "dogs", "poor boys"]
```

The function is in Data.List as far as I remember.